# select query for names of student with marks atleast 60 in two subjects

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me.This may be an easy query  but help me in finding solution the

I have to retrieve the names of students who have secured above 60 in two subjects

hence consider the following table like structure...

```
name|mark1|marks2|marks3|
abc |   60|    70|    20|
mno |  100|    85|    55|
xyz |   20|    20|    20|
```

The o/p must be `abc` and `mno` since they have secured above 60 in two subjects or is there a way in which we can obtain the output using nested query?

Comment: You should normalize your schema, it will make this much easier.

Comment: are you able to change the table structure? because this would be much easier if every mark was in its own row.

Comment: Please fix your question. Your expected results are only right if you mean `at least 60`, not `above 60`.

Comment: @user2910265 That was my point in my first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT name
FROM yourtable
WHERE (mark1>=60)+(marks2>=60)+(marks3>=60) >= 2
```

Comparison operators return `1` when true, `0` when false, so you can add them like this to find out the number of matches.

I assumed you meant *at least 2 subjects*. If you mean *exactly 2 subjects*, change `>= 2` to `= 2`.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5342e/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the 3 possible conditions using `OR`  operator

```
SELECT name
FROM yourtable
WHERE (mark1>60 and mark2>60) or (mark1>60 and mark3>60)
or (mark2>60 and mark3>60)
```

Comment: this is correct, although it doesn't generalize very well. If there were 10 classes and he wanted to find students with 5 high grades, it would be a very long condition.

Comment: @Barmar yes. you are correct. i just give one alternate way of answer for the question asked.

Comment: @helloworld. It will appreciate me if You can say thanks by the way of giving up vote to my answer